# Task is approved and marked as completed but workflow is not

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, 2016, approval, workflow-tasks-list

I am using an out of box SharePoint 2010 - Approval workflow in my SP 2016 site. In some of the cases when we approve the task, the task gets completed and document shows in approved state but the workflow doesn't get marked as completed. This happens only for some of the tasks.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Which state does the workflow display if the status of the workflow is not "Completed"?
[image]

And you could check if there is error information in the workflow information page.

To troubleshoot the issue, you could re-create the out of box SharePoint 2010 - Approval workflow to check if the same issue occurs.

Comment: This workflow is single state Workflow.
There is no error in workflow.
This error I am facing on a particular site only not in any other.

Comment: If the issue only occurs in some tasks, you could terminate the workflow and re-run the workflow in the list item which has the issue.

Comment: The status is displayed as completed.  
Yes, I can do that. But I just wanted to find the root cause of the issue, because re running the workflows might not seem a good practice.

Comment: if the status of the workflow is "completed", then the workflow completes.

Comment: But that's the problem here. I still get that end this workflow link in workflow information page. That I think doesn't come in case of completed workflow.